# Is there a way to use one Hazelcast configuration across multiple cachings?

Tags: caching, hazelcast

I want to cache user data and their Accounts data. The key for both is User ID.

I would like to know how to implement caching across user data and Accounts data using one Hazelcast config ?  Or

Should i use two separate Hazelcast instances

```
config.addMapConfig(
       new MapConfig()
        .setName("CS_DATA")
        .setMaxSizeConfig(new 
                  MaxSizeConfig(Integer.parseInt(cacheSize),                                                        
                  MaxSizeConfig.MaxSizePolicy.valueOf(cachePolicy)))
        .setEvictionPolicy(EvictionPolicy.LRU)                                    
        .setTimeToLiveSeconds(Integer.parseInt(cacheTTL)));
        return config;
    }
```

=============

```
@Cacheable(value = "CS_DATA", key = "#userName" , condition = "#root.target.isAccountCacheRequired()")
public Object getAccounts(String userName) {
            log.info("Cache miss for Accounts data.....Calling otlClient ...." );
```

=============

```
@Cacheable(value =CS_DATA, key = "#userName", condition = "#root.target.isUserCacheRequired()")

public User getUser(String userName) {
   log.info("Cache miss for UserData.....Calling otlClient ...." );
  }
```

======
The current problem that i'm facing is, it overwrites the data as key is same across user and accounts. Any help here would be great

Answer (score 1):

Your data is being overwritten because you use the same cache name in both `Cacheable` annotations (both indicate spring should write to the cache with name `CS_DATA`).

You should make sure you use separate caches (Hazelcast `IMap`s) for each different type you cache (I assume the return type for `getAccounts` is not a `User` object as is the case for `getUser`). For example, you can annotate your cacheable methods like this to use a `CS_ACCOUNT` `IMap` for caching accounts and a separate `CS_USER` IMap for `User` objects:

```
@Cacheable(value = "CS_ACCOUNT", key = "#userName" , condition = "#root.target.isAccountCacheRequired()")
public Object getAccounts(String userName) {
            ...
}

@Cacheable(value = "CS_USER", key = "#userName", condition = "#root.target.isUserCacheRequired()")
public User getUser(String userName) {
   ...
}
```

If you want to configure the two separate `IMap`s with a different configuration, you can use two separate `MapConfig`s in your Hazelcast `Config` like this:

```
public Config getConfig() {
  config.addMapConfig(
    new MapConfig()
      .setName("CS_ACCOUNT")
      .setMaxSizeConfig(new MaxSizeConfig(Integer.parseInt(cacheSize),                                                        
                  MaxSizeConfig.MaxSizePolicy.valueOf(cachePolicy)))
      .setEvictionPolicy(EvictionPolicy.LRU)                                    
      .setTimeToLiveSeconds(Integer.parseInt(cacheTTL)));
  // add another map config for CS_USER IMap
  config.addMapConfig(
    new MapConfig()
      .setName("CS_USER")
      .setMaxSizeConfig(new MaxSizeConfig(Integer.parseInt(userCacheSize),                                                        
                  MaxSizeConfig.MaxSizePolicy.valueOf(cachePolicy)))
      .setEvictionPolicy(EvictionPolicy.LRU)                                    
      .setTimeToLiveSeconds(Integer.parseInt(userCacheTTL)));

  return config;
}
```

If you want multiple `IMap`s to share common configuration, then you can use [wildcards in configuration](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.12/manual/html-single/index.html#using-wildcards). For example, in order to have all `IMap`s starting with `CS_` share a common configuration, use `CS_*` as the map name in `MapConfig` like this:

```
public Config getConfig() {
  // all IMaps with name starting with CS_ will share same max size config, eviction policy and TTL
  config.addMapConfig(
    new MapConfig()
      .setName("CS_*")
      .setMaxSizeConfig(new MaxSizeConfig(Integer.parseInt(cacheSize),                                                        
                  MaxSizeConfig.MaxSizePolicy.valueOf(cachePolicy)))
      .setEvictionPolicy(EvictionPolicy.LRU)                                    
      .setTimeToLiveSeconds(Integer.parseInt(cacheTTL)));
  return config;
}
```

Comment: thank you very much. I think the wildcard is the best approach for me.